# Can all if statements be converted to equivalent switch statements?

Tags: c, if-statement, switch-statement

I think that all if statements like this

```
if(condition){statements;}
```

can be converted to a switch statement like this

```
switch(!(same condition as in if)){case 0:statements;}
```

Am I correct or is there some exception that cannot be converted from if to switch ?

Comment: You are correct.

Comment: Could, but don't. Rarely are switches the neater alternative. An `if` tree has a much clearer meaning than dispatching using a switch.

Comment: Yes  I too prefer if over switch on most occasion. I wrote this question just to find the answer of the question whether all if statements can be converted to switch or not.

Comment: Downvoters please at least tell me why you downvoted so that I can improve the question

Comment: Well, I guess that the voter's thought that your question was not useful.  If you have a single conditional written as an if statement, why change it?  What do you gain, (except possibly a homework answer)?

Comment: The `!` can be confusing, though. If I wanted to do this (*if* I wanted to do this, which I admit is pretty unlikely), I would convert `if(cond) { ifclause; } else { elseclause; }` to `switch(cond) { case 0: elseclause; break; default: ifclause; break; }`

Comment: @SteveSummit nice idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any condition within a `if()` statement evaluates to either **0** or **1**(it is actually any value other than 0). 
 So writing it in **switch()** statement is equivalent to writing `switch(a)`, where **a** can be either **1** or **0**.
 So, you are absolutely correct!

Comment: ... to either 0 or any-value-other-than-0